i'm making an android app to capture audio using plugin.maui.audio but it give me a error
using Plugin.Maui.Audio;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WirelessMic.Services;


public interface IAudioService
{
    Task StartRecordingAsync();
    Task<Stream> StopRecordingAsync();
    bool IsRecording { get; }
}

public class AudioService : IAudioService
{
    private IAudioManager _audioManager;
    private IAudioRecorder _audioRecorder;
    public bool IsRecording => _audioRecorder.IsRecording;
    public AudioService(IAudioManager audioManager)
    {
        _audioManager = audioManager;
        _audioRecorder = audioManager.CreateRecorder();
    }

    public async Task StartRecordingAsync()
    {
        await _audioRecorder.StartAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Stream> StopRecordingAsync()
    {
        var recordedAudio = await _audioRecorder.StopAsync();
        return recordedAudio.GetAudioStream();
    }
}

it show me this error [chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Cannot provide a value for property 'audioService' on type 'WirelessMic.Components.Pages.Microphone'. There is no registered service of type 'WirelessMic.Services.AudioService'.
i already create the services and injected in the microphone.razor page
    .AddAudio();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(AudioManager.Current);


You mention registering the services for the plugin, but the error is about your own AudioService class. Did you register that too?

yes i fixed thank you

Hi @PabloPelinski, you can post the last solution as an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. :)

yes no problem, i add it as services builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAudioService, AudioService>(); i dont know if is correct that has to be a singleton but it work
